# Hadoop MapReduce with a recursive Map

Tags: java, recursion, hadoop, mapreduce

I need to do a MapReduce application in Java, that need to be auto-recursive, that means for each line of input file processed it must check all the lines of the input/Map entries for a condition, verified by a function. Or, by other words, Reducer should call/read the all Map for each pair (key, value) received.

What would be the best way of implement this on Hadoop framework?

I can do this programmatically by reading the input n times or load the input into an hashmap, but i think it may be possible to do it all in the MapReduce paradigm.

Thanks for any help/tip!

*EDIT:* More details, I have (as a result of other jobs) a list of partition of the space of problem with (index,counts) and want to make as output (index, sumOfNearestNeighborsCounts), so for each index, i want to access the map again and for each NearestNeighbor index sum the counts of occurrences. (See also Costi Ciudatu comment)

Comment: Are you saying you want the inputs to go through the map phase multiple times until a condition is met? Or through both the map *and* reduce phases?

Comment: Can you please clarify this for me: you have INPUT -> (A, B) -> MAP -> (C, D) -> REDUCE -> (E, F). For each (C, D) pair that gets to the reducer you need to check all the (C, D) pairs emitted by all the mappers in order to be able to emit an (E, F) result. Is this right ?

Comment: Thank you for the so fast answers!
@Tim Yates, only on reduce phase... in a way i would like to access the all map again for each entry i'm processing in reduce.

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu, Yes, precisely!

Comment: One more thing: can you show me the signature of your check() method ? -- and please point out the types that represent map/reduce input/output keys/values ?

Comment: Just to make sure: NearestNeighbor means "the index(es) with the closest value to a given index", right ? So given (1, 3, 4, 5, 8), the nearest neighbors of 4 will be 3 and 5.

Comment: map-reduce: <Text, Intwritable> (key is a string made by several equalsize '0'/'1'). 
My check() function is a composite of functions. Mainly isNeighbor(String cellIndex, String otherIndex). It checks if otherIndex is a neighbor of cellIndex, and only outputs if true and the sum of counts of neighbors don't overcome ant int parameter, tolerance.

Comment: Oops only after comment i saw your last comment... Index is a string that maps the partition of space according to the values of (numeric) instances. So checking nearaestNeigbors it's not that trivial (but easy!) But in the end it's the same as you say. If data have 2 columns, it will get a set partitions of 2D space, each cell/partition with 8 neighbors (hope that clarifies)

Comment: Can you figure out easily the "neighborhood" of a given index (all the indexes that could POSSIBLY be neighbors) ? I understand that number is not very high: for 2-columns data, you'll have 8 neighborhoods that a given index can be part of.

Comment: Yes, i can verify easily if an index is neighbor of other (done it already). I have to sum on the counts of each neighbor cell. Hard part it grows on 3^D, for 2 columns its 8 neighs, but for 10 columns it's 3^10 neighs, and so on. That's why i want that part also distributed. And since i already got a list of all (cell, count) i just want to iterate on each cell on that same list...

Comment: No, not verify if I1 and I2 are neighbours. I meant: given Ix, find ALL Iy so that neighbor(Ix, Iy).

Comment: Sorry, can't understand your comment (i think we've lost on implementation of check neighbors). I have a list like: (01010010 3), (11110011 5), etc. and a function that can ensure me each index/key is neighbor of another... i need to go one by one on that list and sum the ints of each neighbor, from other indexs that list.

Comment: My question is simple: is there any way you could get the set of ALL the possible neighbours for a given index ? In other words, can you implement a method like this: `Collection<String> getAllPossibleNeighbours(String index)` ? The result may contain indices that do not exist in your input, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: Yes, i have also that function, but it don't solve the problem because i still have to iterate on maps to get the counts. I done it with a simpler structure (both an HashMap and an ArrayList), my question was trying to get done inside hadoop mapreduce framework. But I start to think That it's impossible.

Comment: I hope my (last) answer bellow will prove you wrong... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each index key, you need to emit ALL the possible neighbour indices (that you should be able to produce mathematically).

So, let's take a simple (linear) example. You have a 1-dimensional space with `{I1, I2, I3, I4}`. Neighbour will simply mean "previous or next element": I1 is neighbor to I2 but not to I3.

For every index coming to the mapper, emit one key for each possible neighbour of that index (including itself ! -- we'll define that every index is a possible neighbour of itself but with a special and absurd negative value for count, I'll explain why):

```
<I1, count(I1)> -> <I0, count(I1)>
                -> <I1, -1>
                -> <I2, count(I1)>

<I2, count(I2)> -> <I1, count(I2)>
                -> <I2, -1>
                -> <I3, count(I2)>
```

Now in the reducer you will get the following values for each key:

```
I0: [ count(I1) ]
I1: [ count(I2), -1 ]
I2: [ count(I1), -1, count(I3) ]
...
```

In your reducer, iterate all the values of the neighbours like this:

```
boolean doesExist = false;
int sum = 0;
for (IntWritable value : values) {
    int count = value.get();
    if (count < 0) {
        doesExist = true;
    } else {
        sum += count;
    }
}
if (doesExist) {
    context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
}
```

This way you will exclude (in the above example) I0 and I4, which do not exist and they will have no negative value in their lists.

---

Now, to get closer to your use case, if you need the actual index values also during the iteration (and not only the the counts for all the neighbours), you can do the following:

Instead of emitting simple numbers from the mapper, output some wrapper beans containing both the index and its count. This way you'll be able to exclude some neighbours based on some business constraints or whatever, but you'll always work with only the list of (possible) neighbours for every given index, not with the whole input set:

```
<I1, count(I1)> -> <I0, {I1, count(I1)}>
                -> <I1, {I1, count(I1)}>
                -> <I2, {I1, count(I1)}>
... and so on
```

Now, in the reducer you will get:

```
I0: [ {I1, count(I1)} ]
I1: [ {I1, count(I1)}, {I2, count(I2)} ]
I2: [ {I1, count(I1)}, {I2, count(I2)}, {I3, count(I3)} ]
```

As you can notice, you don't need the artificial `-1` count any more, as for the `doesExist` test you can now check if any wrapper bean in the values list has the same index as the key index.

Even if the number of possible neighbours grows exponentially with the number of dimensions (as you already mentioned), I would say this approach would still perform far better than reading the whole input for every key/value pair and it's a lot better suited in the map/reduce paradigm.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll check and try implement it after dinner and let you know. Thank you so much for you time and effort!

Comment: Now re-reading Tim's answer, if `neighbors(index)` actually means `generateAllPossibleNeighbors(index)`, his answer is actually the _very short_ version of mine (except for handling the details). So if this works, it seems that I only managed to explain what Tim meant (without knowing it) -- so you should probably accept his version as it came far earlier. :)

Comment: Ok, I not implemented yet (i'll do it now) but had check carefully your suggestion and it seems to be a perfect solution for my specific problem, much more than i asked for and embarrassing simpler than any solution i had think!!

Comment: In fact none of you give a direct answer to my question (how to do recursion on a map) but directly help to solve my specific problem, so in that way I think @Costi Ciudatu answer it's better, because it goes in all details, and plain justify why, in that case, a recursion it's not needed. Thank You again!

Answer (score 0):

In your map phase, output a key for each neighbor, and then sum in the reduce. Pseudocode:

```
function map(index, count):
  for neighbor in neighbors(index):
     emit(neighbor, count)

function reduce(index, counts):
  total = sum(counts)
  emit(index, total)
```

It isn't "recursive", but it should solve your specific problem if I understand it correctly.

Comment: Thank Tim. My problem is that to get the count of neighbor, i need first to select which cells are neighbors, meaning that either i read the entries again or previously load the entries on a HashMap or similar or, somehow, manage to read the Map recursively. It's to apply to large datasets (>4Gb at least) so any optimization of those readings would be a bless.